# Listview do Android com lentidão

Tags: java, listview, android-adapter

O que pode estar ocasionando a lentidão?

Código do `Adaptador`:

```
public class Adaptador extends BaseAdapter{
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    Context contexto;
    String[][] datos;
    int[] datosImg;

    public Adaptador(Context conexto, String[][] datos, int[] imagenes)
    {
        this.contexto = conexto;
        this.datos = datos;
        this.datosImg = imagenes;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater)conexto.getSystemService(conexto.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista, null);

        TextView titulo = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.tvTitulo);
        TextView duracion = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.tvDuracion);
        TextView director = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.tvDirector);

        ImageView imagen = (ImageView) vista.findViewById(R.id.ivImagen);
        RatingBar calificacion = (RatingBar) vista.findViewById(R.id.ratingBarPel);

        titulo.setText(datos[i][0]);
        director.setText(datos[i][1]);
        duracion.setText("Duração " + datos[i][2]);
        imagen.setImageResource(datosImg[i]);
        calificacion.setProgress(Integer.valueOf(datos[i][3]));

        return vista;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return datosImg.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Está testando a aplicação onde? direto no mobile ou pelo desktop?

Comment: Testei no Celular e no Emulador

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu código não está reusando a View e está sempre inflando. O método é executado várias vezes e sempre infla. Você pode aproveitar a convertView. Neste caso, faça isso:

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     View vista = convertView;

    if(vista==null)
        vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista, parent, false);

    TextView titulo = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.tvTitulo);
    TextView duracion = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.tvDuracion);
    TextView director = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.tvDirector);

    ImageView imagen = (ImageView) vista.findViewById(R.id.ivImagen);
    RatingBar calificacion = (RatingBar) vista.findViewById(R.id.ratingBarPel);

    titulo.setText(datos[i][0]);
    director.setText(datos[i][1]);
    duracion.setText("Duração " + datos[i][2]);
    imagen.setImageResource(datosImg[i]);
    calificacion.setProgress(Integer.valueOf(datos[i][3]));

    return vista;
}
```

Claro que existem outras formas de melhorar, como usando o padrão ViewHolder. Mas nesse caso deve ser isso.

Comment: public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View vista = convertView;

        if(vista==null)
            vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista, null);

Comment: Acontece um erro "Cannot assing a value to final variable 'vista' "

Comment: Tire o `final`, ou então troque as duas últimas linhas que citou por `final View vista = (convertView != null ? convertView : inflater.inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista, null));`

Comment: Ele compilou porem quando eu abro a activity o app para de funcionar, acontece quando eu tiro o final e quando eu troco as linhas

Comment: LogCat     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup)' on a null object reference

Comment: coloque o código exatamente como botei agora. Tire o final e deixe como está. Antigamente funcionava?

Comment: veja a linha, mudei pra inflater.inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista, parent, false);

Comment: Funcionava quando tinha o primeiro código que eu postei, porem ficava dando muitos  lags

Comment: O app compila porem quando abre a activity da listview o app para

Comment: mudou o que alterei lá? vá depurando e veja em que linha dá erro.

Comment: essa linha está realmente após o if? ou então coloque dentro das chaves do if pra testar         vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista, parent, false);

Comment: A linha que da erro é E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: mas depurando linha por linha, qual a que dá erro?

Comment: Consegui abri a activity porem ainda continua dando lags